# List all the filename and the first row (File header) in the file name

Tags: windows, powershell

The code I am using is below and it just lists the filename and column name individually:

```
$list1 = @(Get-ChildItem *.txt |select name)
$list2 = @(Get-Content *.txt -First 1 )
$add = $list1+$list2 >
```

The desired output should be:

```
Filename1|column1
Filename1|column2
Filename1|column3

Filename2|column1
Filename2|column2
Filename2|column3

Filename3|column1
Filename3|column2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your desired output list (why are there multiple columns when you talk about listing filenames and the first row?). However, you could iterate over all files, read the first line and concat them together using a format string:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}|{1}' -f $_.Name, ($_ | Get-Content -Head 1)     
}
```

**Edit:**

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $filename = $_.Name
    ($_ | Get-Content -Head 1) -split '\|' | ForEach-Object {
        '{0}|{1}' -f $filename, $_
    }
}
```

Comment: File1 contains 3 column in the first line, File2 contains 3 column in the first line , File3 contains 2 column in the first line. The output should be filename+columnname

Comment: Then your question is **missing information**. How is the column separated? Maybe post a sample.

Comment: The columns in the files are separated with '|' delimiter. You code returns Filename1|columnname1|columnname2|columnname3 but i need Filename1|columnname1,  Filename1|columnname2, Filename1|columnname3